# What is the difference between a spindump and a process sample?

Tags: macos

Apple's official documentation says this:

- Sample Process: Creates a report on a selected process over a period
  of 3 seconds.
- Spindump: Creates a report for unresponsive apps that were terminated
  using force quit.

But I'm looking for a more in-depth explanation of a difference between the two. Particularly, in which circumstances would you debug with sampling a process and with a spindump? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is based on limited personal experience: it's probably very incomplete)

A spindump seems to contain much more information than a sample:

- A sample contains thread stack traces for the threads of a single, chosen application; but a spindump captures stack traces for *all* running applications
- A spindump seems to capture extra information like rendering framerate for all apps
- A spindump requires superuser privileges to capture
- By default, a sample is taken over 3 seconds, but a spindump is taken over 10 seconds

So, a sample is much more focused, presumably contains less personal information, but potentially lacks data for investigating complex issues that involve multiple processes.
Anecdotically, I think developers usually ask for a sample when trying to diagnose a performance issue, so there's probably further meaningful differences between the two.